# Error when reinstall angular2 web pack

Tags: angular

I don't no why, my web running normal, but when I reinstall npm angular2 with new version angular2 2.4.3, old version 2.4.0, its have error this.
[Now is running web is die](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySjvu.png)

please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Try to active the 'pause script execution' button (||), and you will see where is exactly the error. I think also you have an error in your template, because it's returning an undefined object, then the 'toUpperCase' is not able to do anything.